# Roots of Polynomial Equation, $P(z)=z^4-iz^3+8z-8i$

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm having difficulty finding the roots of $P(z)=z^4-iz^3+8z-8i$ as I'm not really sure where to start. I tried factoring out z but I didn't know what to beyond that.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `I tried factoring out z` That's a good start, if you mean $z^3(z-i)+8(z-i)\,$. Where did you get stuck after that?

Comment: Usually these sort of problems are only set as exercises when there is a fairly obvious factorisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
P(z)&=z^4-iz^3+8z-8i\\
&=z^3(z-i)+8(z-i)\\
&=(z^3+8)(z-i)\\
&=(z+2)(z^2-2z+4)(z-i)\\
z&=-2,i\quad\text{or}\quad1\pm i\sqrt{3}
\end{align}

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg fixed. Thanks.